# Is it possible to have two strokes on an SVG element?

Tags: css, svg

I have some SVG elements (rectangles). When I double click on these I add a class to the rectangle.

This class is like so :

```
.highlighted {
    stroke: green;
    stroke-width : 3px;     
}
```

Basically a green border. I tried the class like this :

```
.highlighted {
    border: 3px solid green;
}
```

But it doesn't work as I'm working with SVG not HTML.

My question is, is it possible to have multiple strokes on one SVG rectangle element ?

Comment: Am I the only one who got this wrong ? :)

Comment: You are mixing up HTML and SVG in your question which has caused some turbulences in the answers and comments. Some mistook the question for  dealing with SVG since you tagged it [tag:D3.js] and mentioned the `stroke`. However, there is no `border` attribute in SVG. On the other hand, you mentioned styling a `div` which is HTML and doesn't know of `stroke`. Please clarify your question and what exactly you are after. That will likely bring up much more helpful answers.

Comment: no wonder the border wasn't working with SVG haha I shall change my question :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At present the answer is no.

You would need a second rectangle to create the other 'stroke'.

There is hope however

Extract from the [**W3 spec**](http://www.w3.org/TR/svg-strokes/)

> SVG 2 supports multiple strokes, which we will need updated wording to handle in this specification.

As for borders...they do not apply to SVG internal elements such as paths and rectangles etc....only the *full* SVG itself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it with a rectangle element but I can think of a way for circle and ellipse elements

```html
    <svg height="150" width="500">
        <defs>
            <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
                <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255)" />
                <stop offset="20%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255)" />
                <stop offset="20%" style="stop-color:rgb(100,255,255)" />
                <stop offset="40%" style="stop-color:rgb(100,255,255)" />
                <stop offset="40%" style="stop-color:rgb(50,5,255)" />
                <stop offset="60%" style="stop-color:rgb(50,5,255)" />
                <stop offset="60%" style="stop-color:rgb(50,50,25)" />
                <stop offset="80%" style="stop-color:rgb(50,50,25)" />
                <stop offset="80%" style="stop-color:rgb(250,0,0)" />
                <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(250,0,0)" />
            </radialGradient>
        </defs>
        <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="55" fill="url(#grad1)" />
        <ellipse cx="250" cy="70" rx="85" ry="55" fill="url(#grad1)" />
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have multiples borders on a div (with `outline` and `border`), but not on SVG.
You can to try with multiple paths.
My SVG knowledge is pretty minimal, but I think it should be possible to achieve these results using SVG Vector Effects.
"Vector effects allows stroking to be applied multiple times."
http://dev.w3.org/SVG/modules/vectoreffects/master/SVGVectorEffectsPrimer.html

Also, read this, please:
https://svgwg.org/specs/strokes/#SpecifyingStrokeAlignment

Comment: It is possible to have two borders. What is wrong with the answer?

Comment: This is an SVG question which does not support borders on internal SVG elements.

Comment: @Paulie_D That was my first thought because it mentioned D3 and the `stroke` attribute. But the question doesn't have a SVG tag and the title clearly mentions setting a border on a `div`.

Comment: Thank you @altocumulus! I edited the answer, but the question is not ok.

Comment: @MadalinaTaina I agree with you on the assessment of the question, but please undo your edit or add further details. At least, your answer was on the right track, now it is pretty much worthless as you mention paths, which are not a feature of HTML.

Comment: @MadalinaTaina I commented on the question which now got revised. It actually **is** about SVG. Now, unfortunately, your answer is a bit off the mark. You may want to refine it.

Comment: @altocumulus It is an example with multiple paths there. I don't know how to explain in other way. http://dev.w3.org/SVG/modules/vectoreffects/master/SVGVectorEffectsPrimer.html

Comment: Vector effects were never implemented - that's an abandoned spec.