# How to set different colors in different parts of stroke in html SVG

Tags: svg, stroke

How can I achieve something like this using SVG?

[image: Required output]

Comment: Create a complete circle in one colour and either a partial circular path or a circle with stroke-dasharray for the other.

Comment: Imagine circle to be just an example and replace with complex path.
If so, then the question is vaild: 

How do i paint part of path with one color and the rest with another?

And seems than answer is now at this time. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32394628/1593719

Answer (score 5):

You would need two different `circle` elements, one for the underlying gray color and the other for the blue stroke, then apply a `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` to the blue stroke.

```css
 .track,
.filled {
  stroke-width: 10;
  fill: none;
}

.track {
  stroke: #eee;
}

.filled {
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-dashoffset: 110;
  stroke-dasharray: 440;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 190 190">
  <circle class="track" cx="80" cy="80" r="70" />
  <circle class="filled" cx="80" cy="80" r="70" />
</svg>
```